# Error when changing the smtp host in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

> 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message.

I have an ASP.NET web application that has a contact page with a form. It was going to well until I changed the host. For example, if I change the host to `smtp.live.com` instead of `smtp.gmail.com` I got the error that is above. My question is, if my host is from my gmail account, it works fine but if I change it, it doesn't work. I've already searched other questions but they are different from mine and can't find any suitable answer on Google.

My code is the following:

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@hotmail.com", "mymail@hotmail.com");
        mm.Subject = TextBox1.Text;
        mm.Body = "Name: " + txtName.Text + "<br /><br />Email: " + txtEmail.Text + "<br />" + TextBox2.Text;

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));
        }

        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        //smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
        NetworkCred.UserName = "mymail@hotmail.com";
        NetworkCred.Password = "xxxxxxxx";
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
        lblMessage.Text = "Email Sent SucessFully.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851319/how-to-add-smtp-hotmail-account-to-send-mail ?

Comment: yes, it was one of the first attempts.

Comment: Check this link and exception and solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016305/phpmailer-exceptionsendasdeniedexception-mapiexceptionsendasdenied?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: PHP is not my thing so..

Comment: Please put your found answer in an answer and not in the question :)

Comment: Ok, sorry! Done! :)

Answer (score 1):

> ANSWER: Through this question -> [PHPMailer .Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016305/phpmailer-exceptionsendasdeniedexception-mapiexceptionsendasdenied?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) , I changed the "sender@hotmail.com" to another mail of mine and worked.