# "Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 5.2.0 STOR EDRV "

Tags: php, laravel-5

I would like to send an email with an attachment. Using smtp.office365.com

### **IN Production: ubuntu**

smtp.office365.com - Laravel 5.

Expected response code 250 but got code "554", with message "554 5.2.0 
STOR EDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied;   Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot  submit message.

### **IN Localhost :**

Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send   anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [xxxxxx.xxxx.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]"

### .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxx@org.io
MAIL_PASSWORD='xxxxx'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Are you changing the `From` address?

Comment: [Possible dupe for production error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016305/phpmailer-exceptionsendasdeniedexception-mapiexceptionsendasdenied) - [Possible dupe for localhost error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342884/the-server-response-was-5-7-57-smtp-client-was-not-authenticated-to-send-anony?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Yes I changed from address.

Comment: I am currently experiencing this exact issue. I am investigating will post results here.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For Office 365, `From_Email` must be the same as the logon user. You are changing the From address, and that is not allowed.

Comment: I believe you can as long as the permissions are set. I've got an application that is sending using the email from the env that has permissions to send from another email.

Answer (score 6):

Change your setting in mail.php file

```
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'your-mail-host'),
  'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'your-mail@host.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Your User Name'),
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using this to test:

```
Mail::send('welcome',[],function($message){ $message->to('xxxxx@xxxxxx.com')->subject('laravel mail'); });
```

This code made this error

Swift_TransportException with message 'Expected response code 250 but got code "554"

I added a from clause that matched my config in .env

```
Mail::send('welcome',[],function($message){ $message->from('xxxxx@xxxxxxx.com')->to('xxxxx@xxxxxx.com')->subject('laravel mail'); });
```

I got the email.